# HttpClient throws an error "An error was encountered while creating the response"

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-http-client

I am integrating an API in which I have to send my request in encrypted mode and for that I am using httpClient but when I tried this I am getting:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
> An error was encountered while creating the response
> at vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:173

Now I have done same process using Postman but in that I got desired response:

[image: postman image]

Now I am unable to catch what is the real issue behind it;  is there any header related issue or is there anything else?

The process for this API calling is also described as below

```
$config = 'ALL_DATA_FOR_REQUEST';
$httpClient = Http::timeout($config->timeout);
$httpClient->withHeaders($config->headers);

       try {
            if ($config->method === 'GET') {
                $gatewayResponse = $httpClient->get($config->url, $config->encryptedRequestData ?? $config->requestData);
            } elseif ($config->method === 'POST') {
                $encryptedRequestData = $config->encryptedRequestData;
                if ($encryptedRequestData && is_string($encryptedRequestData)) {
                    $httpClient->withBody($encryptedRequestData, trim($config->headers['Content-Type']));
                    $encryptedRequestData = [];
                }
                $gatewayResponse = $httpClient->post(
                    $config->url,
                    $encryptedRequestData ?? $config->requestData
                );
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $curlMessage = $e->getMessage();
            preg_match('/^[^\d]*(\d+)/', $curlMessage, $curlCode);
            return \Ipay::response([
                'statusCode' => 'ISE',
                'status' => $curlMessage,
                'data' => [
                    'curlCode' => $curlCode[1] ?? '-',
                ],
            ]);
        }
```

I have also set my header content-type as text/plain.

Through some debugging I have found something which I think is related to it:

[image: error in curlFactory]

This error is found in curlfactory.php file in guzzlehttp and I think this is somewhere pointing me some error;
so is this some third party error which I am consuming.

Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

After researching I finally found that actual headers are

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

[more details on X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

but the vendor was sending x-frame option header which was not correct and it was caught in HTTP client

after this i contacted to vendor and they corrected it.